# call NSString whit multiple parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, mpmediaitemcollection

I am a beginner and maybe it is a trivial question.
I have this method:

```
-(NSString *)getInfoFormediaItem:(MPMediaItemCollection *)list {    
NSString *trackCount;

if ([list count] > 0) {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%lu Songs", @""), (unsigned long)[list count]];
} else if([list count] == 1) {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"1 Song", @"")];
} else {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"0 Song", @"") ];
}

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", trackCount];
}
```

I would like to call it here with a **MPMediaItemCollection**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if( cell == nil )
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
} 

MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *playl = [playlistsQuery collections];
MPMediaItem *rowItem = [playl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
MPMediaItemCollection * collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowItem]];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self getInfoFormediaItem:collection];
}
```

I would like to get the number of tracks in each playlist.
It doesn't work. How do I fix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The perform selector thing you have going on there is not necessary and a little strange. The reason it is always 0 is because you never pass an argument into your method. So [nil count] is always 0. You should call this directly. [self getInfoForMediaItem: someMPMediaItemCollection];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why are you using `performSelector:withObject:`? Just call the method directly:

   ```
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self getInfoFormediaItem:collection];
   ```
2. Why are you passing `nil` to the `withObject:` parameter? That's why your code goes to the `else`. `list` is `nil` so `[list count]` will always be `0`. You need to pass an actual instance of a `MPMediaItemCollection`.
3. Why are you needlessly using `stringWithFormat:` for the 1 and 0 count checks? Just do:

   ```
   -(NSString *)getInfoFormediaItem:(MPMediaItemCollection *)list {    
       NSString *trackCount;

       if ([list count] > 1) {
           trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%lu Songs", @""), (unsigned long)[list count]];
       } else if([list count] == 1) {
           trackCount = NSLocalizedString(@"1 Song", @"");
       } else {
           trackCount = NSLocalizedString(@"0 Song", @"");
       }

       return trackCount;
   }
   ```
4. Based on your updated question, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code isn't correct for the getting the media collection. The `collections`method returns an array of `MPMediaCollection` objects, not `MPMediaItem` objects. You need:

   ```
   MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
   NSArray *playl = [playlistsQuery collections];
   MPMediaItemCollection *collection = playl[indexPath.row];
   ```

   Now you can use `collection` when you call `getInfoFormediaItem:`.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. Yes just 'return trackCount;' . About :someList I have _Use of undeclared identifier someList_ and it requires a parameter of type MPMediaItemCollection. What parameter? Thanks for the patience

Comment: My use of someList was meant as a placeholder. You need to replace that with an actual instance of a MPMediaItemCollection.

Comment: Can you give me an example? In cellForRowAtIndexPath I need a instance of a MPMediaItemCollection? MPMediaItemCollection *count;

Comment: `MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    NSArray *playl = [playlistsQuery collections];
    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [playl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` but return 1 song

Comment: Update your question with the additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't need to call this statement:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [self performSelector:@selector(getInfoFormediaItem:) withObject:nil];
```

in your "getInfoFormediaItem"method. You do that in your "cellforrowataIndexPath" method when you define the cell,just call like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self getInfoFormediaItem:This_Is_A_List_You_Wanna_Pass_To_The_Method];
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: With This_Is_A_List_You_Wanna_Pass_To_The_Method what have I need to pass? It requires a parameter of type MPMediaItemCollection

Comment: I try `MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    NSArray *playl = [playlistsQuery collections];
    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [playl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; MPMediaItemCollection * collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowItem]];` but return always 1.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems pointed out by other posters, your if statement will not work as you want it to:

```
if ([list count] > 0) {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%lu Songs",
    @""), (unsigned long)[list count]];
} else if([list count] == 1) {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"1 Song", @"")];
} else {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"0 Song", @"") ];
}
```

The "if ... >0" clause will match first, before checking for a value of 1, since 1 is > 0. Thus the "if ... == 1" will never evaluate as true. You need to reorder that if statement:

```
if ([list count] == 1) {
    trackCount = NSLocalizedString(@"1 Song", @"");
else if ([list count] > 0) {
    trackCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%lu Songs",
    @""), (unsigned long)[list count]];
} 
else 
{
    trackCount = NSLocalizedString(@"0 Songs", @"");
}
```